# Upgrading Typescript on Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently working on a relatively old project using Angular 6. I want to upgrade to typescript@>=3.7, mainly for optional chaining.

So the question is, is there a workaround to upgrading Typescript without upgrading Angular which may break a lot of functionality?

I have tried to upgrade Typescript normally using npm but Angular 6 doesn't like that and won't start even after I disabled the warning.

#### Warning

```
@angular/compiler-cli@6.1.7 requires typescript@'>=2.7.2 <2.10' but 4.0.2 was found instead.
Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.

Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.

    npm install typescript@'>=2.7.2 <2.10'

To disable this warning run "ng config cli.warnings.typescriptMismatch false".
```

#### Error

```
ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.10.0 but 4.0.2 was found instead.
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Thanks!

Comment: *"Angular 6 doesn't like that and won't start"* - Errors? If yes, please provide.

Comment: Added the printed warning and error.

Comment: @wentjun Yes, thanks!